# Where $p$ is a prime number and $n$ is an integer, let $f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}[in^{i-1}]$. Prove that if $f(m)=f(n)$(mod $p$) then $m=n$(mod $p$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, I received a hint to "set $f(n) = s'(n)$ and compute $s(x)$ by computing $s(x) - x*s(x)$, now plug in $x=n$ and you'll have a formula for $f(n)$" but still not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Did you follow the hint? If so, what have you done and where are you stuck at?

Comment: @CalvinLin to be perfectly honest I don't really understand the hint either and was just hoping for any type of clarity

Comment: Their goal is to get you to find a closed expression for $f(n)$, and the hint tells you what to do (if you're not seen it before). So, following the hint, what would $s(n)$ be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ s(n) = \ldots $

> $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} n^i = \frac{ n^p - n } { n - 1 } $.

So $f(n) = s'(n) = \ldots $

> $$\frac{ (p-1)n^{p+1} - p n^p + n } { (n-1)^2 n}$$

So if $ f(n) \equiv f(m) \pmod{p} $, then ...

> Do some work. If you get stuck, show your work and explain why you're stuck.

Hence, $n -1  \equiv m -1  \pmod{p}$

Note: Because of the denominator, you might want to deal with the $ n \equiv 0, 1 \pmod{p} $ cases separately.

Comment: So if we know that $f(n)$ is congruent to $f(m)$ mod $p$ how does that not necessarily imply that $m$ is congruent to $n$ mod $p$?

Comment: @itseasybutton It depends on the specific function right? Hence the "do some work". E.g. if $ f(x) = x^2 $, then $f(1) \equiv f(2) \pmod{3} $ but $ 1 \not \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: honestly this is horrifically embarrassing for me but I don't even know what "work" I am supposed to do, I'm in this class that probably should've had some pre-reqs listed but it didn't and everything is just flying over my head and I have to resort to this forum every week just to hope I can barely scrape by and pass, sorry for the rant everything is just chaotic at the moment

Comment: @itseasybutton Show your work. What have you tried, even if it doesn't seem to go anywhere. E.g. Could you have stated $s(n)$ by yourself? ( I believe you should be able to, if you know what derivatives are). Could you have evaluated $s'(n)$? Supposed you're stuck at $ f(n) \equiv f(m)$, then explain what gets you stuck and what you're trying and why it doesn't seem to work. That would help others understand what parts they need to be explaining (and they are more willing to explain it in detail), as opposed to you sitting back and being spoon-fed in this forum.

Comment: what should I try to continue on from $f(n) = f(m)$ mod $p$? I would love to show you my work but I don't have any because I don't understand how to approach the problem. I don't want to be spoon fed, I want to understand what I am supposed to do to reach a solution. I'm not "stuck" because to be stuck you have to actually be able to start in the first place. I also just want to add that I am thankful for you taking time out of your day to at least try to help me because I understand why this would be annoying for you to deal with

Comment: @itseasybutton So suppose $f(n) \equiv f(m) \pmod{p}$, what else can you write down after that? E.g. Can you substitute the expression for $f(n)$? And after that? What can we do? Maybe we could simplify the expression by using $ p k \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$? What about $ n^{p+1} \pmod {p}$? After you've done those, where are you (stuck) at?

Comment: so for example the term $pn^{p}$ would "disappear" because anything times $p$ mod $p$ is going to be $0$ right? and then for $n^{p+1}$ mod $p$ I'm sure there's some neat theorem out there that would allow me to substitute/simplify but I am drawing a blank

Comment: @itseasybutton Right, so listing out where you're stuck is going to be very helpful. E.g. Now I can ask "Do you know what FLT in number theory is?"

Comment: I am familiar but I am having a hard time seeing how to apply it here, if $n^{p-1} = 1$ (mod $p$) then what can I say about $n^{p+1}$?

Comment: Multiply throughout by $n^2$.

Comment: so then I would have $(p-1)n^{p+3}+n^{3}$ in the numerator and $(n-1)^{2}n^{3}$ in the denominator correct?

Comment: Nono. I meant that if $ n^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ (which isn't always true for all $n$), then multiplying by $n^2$ gives us $ n^ { p+1 } \equiv n^2 \pmod{p}$.

Comment: Okay I see now, so then I can substitute $n^{2}$ for the term and then have $pn^{2}$ (which becomes 0) $-n^{2}+n$ in the numerator and the denominator remains unchanged

Comment: Yup, continue going.

Comment: If I am not mistaken it further simplifies to $\frac{1}{-n+1}$ and then what can I do with that from there?

Comment: If $ \frac{1}{n-1} \equiv \frac{1}{m-1} \pmod{p}$, what can you conclude from there?

Comment: I can say that $n-1=m-1$ (mod $p$) which then allows me to say that $n=m$ (mod $p$)?

Comment: Sort of / mostly there. One thing to be careful about, you somewhat skipped over the case of $n \equiv 0, 1 \pmod{p}$, in which case we're looking at things like $ \frac{1}{0} , \frac{0}{0} \pmod{p}$, which is why I mentioned dealing with them separately if you're not comfortable with such modular arithmetic multiplication.

Comment: Okay perfect I see now and I think I understand how to round out the proof. Thank you so much for your help and for being patient with me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @itseasybutton In future, follow this process of "state what you've done and where you're stuck", so that others know what kind / how much of guidance to provide, based on how much you're shown you understand (instead of having to guess at what you know, in which case it's easy to guess that you're very familiar with the basics like reducing modular arithmetic expressions)